# Determine the sample space when applying the law of total probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let us consider a countable probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A}:=2^{\Omega},\mathbb{P})$. For a decomposition $A_{1},\dots, A_{n}$ of $\Omega$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A_{i})>0$, we have the following Law of Total Probability: $$\mathbb{P}(B)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(B|A_{i})\mathbb{P}(A_{i}),\ \forall\ B\in\mathcal{A}.$$

I do not have problem proving and understanding the equation. I can also apply it to solve elementary probability problems, but in "real" example, if think further, I found myself stuck in determining the sample space.

---

Example 1: this example comes from the wikipedia. Suppose that in a city, there are only two factories supply light bulbs. Factory $X$ supplies $60\%$ of total bulbs available and factory $Y$ supplies the rest $40\%$. We know that factory $X$'s bulbs defection rate is $0.01$ and factory $Y$'s bulbs defection rate is $0.05$. We want to know the probability that when a citizen in this city buys a light bulb from the market, the citizen will get a non-defective product. Consider the events $$A_{1}:=\{\text{the light bulb is from factory X}\},\ \ A_{2}:=\{\text{the light bulb is from factory Y}\}$$ $$B:=\{\text{the light bulb is not defective}\}.$$ We know that $\mathbb{P}(A_{1})=0.6$, $\mathbb{P}(A_{2})=0.4$, $\mathbb{P}(B|A_{1})=0.99$ an $\mathbb{P}(B|A_{2})=0.95$. Thus, it is ready to compute $\mathbb{P}(B)$ using the law.

**However**, what is the sample space here? To apply the law, we need $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ to be a **decomposition** of $\Omega$. In other words, $$\Omega=A_{1}+A_{2}=\{\{\text{the bulb is from X}\}, \{\text{the bulb is from Y}\}\},$$ where $"+"$ means disjoint union. But if $\Omega$ is as such, is $B$ an event? We need $B$ to be a subset of $\Omega$, right?

---

Example 2: Consider n urn containing $M$ balls, $m$ of which are white. Suppose that we are going to draw two balls without replacement. And we want to know the probability that the second ball drawn is white. Define the events $$A:=\{\text{the first ball drawn is white}\}\ \ \text{and}\ \ B:=\{\text{the second ball drawn is white}\}.$$ What we want to know is $\mathbb{P}(B)$. By the law of total probability, we have $$\mathbb{P}(B)=\mathbb{P}(BA)+\mathbb{P}(BA^{c}).$$ It is to compute that $$\mathbb{P}(BA)=\dfrac{m(m-1)}{M(M-1)}\ \ \text{and}\ \ \mathbb{P}(BA^{c})=\dfrac{m(M-m)}{M(M-1)}.$$ Therefore, $\mathbb{P}(B)=\frac{m}{M}.$

**Well again**, the reason why we can write $B=BA+BA^{c}$ is that $A+A^{c}=\Omega$. But in a case, how can $B$ be an event?

---

I am not sure what I get wrong here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that in order to model your examples, you need to define the sample space in such a way that $B$ is an event. Remember that *elements* of the sample space (outcomes) are different from *subsets* of the sample space (events), and a "decomposition" is a partition of $\Omega$ into disjoint *events*.

In the first example, you could have

$$\Omega=\{(\text{the bulb is from $X$ and not defective}),(\text{the bulb is from $X$ and defective}),(\text{the bulb is from $Y$ and not defective}),(\text{the bulb is from $Y$ and defective})\}.$$

Then your events are:

$$A_1=\{\text{the bulb is from $X$}\}=\{(\text{the bulb is from $X$ and not defective}),(\text{the bulb is from $X$ and defective})\},\\
A_2=\{\text{the bulb is from $Y$}\}=\{(\text{the bulb is from $Y$ and not defective}),(\text{the bulb is from $Y$ and defective})\},\\
B=\{\text{the bulb is not defective}\}=\{(\text{the bulb is from $X$ and not defective}),(\text{the bulb is from $Y$ and not defective})\}.
$$

Comment: ah!!!! Yeah $A_{1}$ can be a union of two "elements" from the sample space.  My bad. Nice answer.